# Do water bottles on sidewalk/corners prevent dogs/cats from peeing?

Tags: zoology

It's very common, at least in Italy, to see bottles of water near walls in sidewalk and I've been told it's because it prevents dogs and cats from peeing on the wall. Is this actually the case and why wouldn't a dog/cat pee on it?

[online reference](http://www.neatorama.com/2007/10/05/do-water-bottles-on-sidewalk-discourage-dogs-from-peeing/#!B2Fbt)

Comment: Here's an [article about them from Japan](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2005/05/19/reference/pet-bottles/). Here's a [program testing out the theory](http://www.japanprobe.com/2010/11/05/plastic-water-bottles-vs-cats/). "Has someone's house burnt down from the lens effect of water-filled plastic bottles?" might be a nice additional question...

Comment: I know here only documented stuff is relevant but we had lot of issues with cat smell and it stopped once we put water bottles around the house.

Answer (score 5):

This thing is most likely **not** effective.

While not highly scientific, Mythbusters did test this on cats (Episode 214). The result: cats completely ignored the bottles.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9LrhZRZvD4

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is based on my [much longer and more extensive answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/stop-free-roaming-dogs-from-entering-my-property/14943#14943) to a LifeHacker.SE question on the same subject:*

The [Cats Away Blog](http://catsaway.org/water-bottle-and-cat-myth/) declares it to be a myth:

> The practice is so popular in fact that a year or two ago a Japanese breakfast TV show decided to put it to the test and while you might not understand the commentary, it is pretty obvious that they put the superstition to bed once and for all.

[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/critters/wild/lawn.asp) rates it as undetermined, not showing any evidence either way:

> Is there anything to this notion or not? Who knows?